# Rebuilding the Facebook graph in my application !

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a social network where each user is registered through Facebook. So I own the uid and all the friends' uid for each user.

Question 1 - Taking an user, is it possible to **show all Facebook's friends** already registered in my application
Question 2 - When an user visit another profile's user (in my app) what do you think is the fastest way to **show him the level of distance between that profile and him** (For level of distance, I mean, the Facebook distance in my little Facebook graph pulled out by all the friend's list I got)

Comment: Thanks to everybody I've done it :D :D :D ... I want to say to everyone else reading this post that Facebook has the limitation to 600 query per 600 seconds (Today 18 July 2011) if you try to stress it more, it will reject your other queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: It is possible. To get the friends of the current user, use this URL (I grabbed that from the dev docs): https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=2227470867|2.AQBEjXxd_fW52bvk.3600.1310130000.0-578251212|QCORnV4GfaN0quTTIR38b5HuC1g

Q2: That's a very tricky one, since you can't read a users friend's list of friends. You would  then need to keep track of connections on your end. You might be able to do some with FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/

Comment: In order to accomplish the point number 2. Do you suggest me to associate in my data model another table FACEBOOK_FRIENDS that will have many to one relationship with the profile and will contain all the facebook friends of a particoular profile ? In this way I'll always have the information available and I can build more performant alghorithms... to build my little Facebook Graph,  what do you think?

Comment: If you really want to rebuild the Facebook Graph, it would be a many-to-many relationships between profiles, as everyone can be friends with anyone. I'd simply have the profiles in one table, and the connections between profiles in another table to accomplish an m-n relationship.

Comment: mmm ... actually, what I meant is to associate a table to each user with the list of all the facebook friend that are present in my platform ... I don't know which approach is better

Comment: You can achieve the same by having a table called e.g. FacebookConnections having two columns, one uid1 and the second uid2. Then to make two profiles friends you would add any of the two's UID as uid1 and the other's as uid2. Then, with any profile ID, you can lookup this table to see who they're connected to.

Comment: I have to lookup this table twice (once per side) because an user can be friend of someone in both ways.<br/> I would like to evaluate if the performance is better with my approach or using the one you are proposing. I want also to highlight two aspects: If I store the friends on my own table, I have to implement some refresh routines that after a certain period check if the friends of the user are changed and refresh the related table. Another aspect is that check if an user is two level distance from you can be not so straightforward: I have to check each friend and the friend of him.....

Comment: ... the Facebook average friend is 135 so it's 18225 iteration per user. What if I store the entire graph on my application and refresh it ? in that case, I can use graph's algorithm to browse mine. I really need to evaluate the performance aspect.

Comment: I can't even imagine the problems you'll run into, trying to copy Facebook's entire graph. Before thinking about performance of your table look-ups, have you considered the limitations of the Graph API? If you want to store their entire graph, how can you avoid being limited on a daily, not to mention hourly basis? AFAIK, Facebook's rate limiting is 1/5 of Twitter's, making it more than difficult to keep the friendships between ~750 million users in sync.

Comment: Actually, I'm not trying to copy the entire Facebook graph, I'm just developing a service that use Facebook. I want to let the user know the distance Facebook in my platform based on the info I got. I'll never reach the entire graph